# Python Code Condensation

Tags: python, function

I am new and a beginner. I need help condensing `play_game()` below. I need to get it to 18 lines. I would like to call the `if` and `else` function from within this code to shorten it by that many lines.

```
def play_game():  # def the plag game function which is the main control of the game
    level = get_level()
    quiz = game_data[level]['quiz']
    print quiz
    answers_list =  game_data[level]['answers']
    blanks_index = 0
    answers_index = 0
    guesses = 3

    while blanks_index < len(blanks):
        user_answer = raw_input("So what's your answer to question " + blanks[blanks_index] + "? : ")       #while, if and else to increment the blanks, answers, and guesses
        if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,answers_index) == "right_answer":
            print "\n Lucky Guess!\n"
            quiz = quiz.replace(blanks[blanks_index], user_answer.upper())                                  #prints appropriate responses
            blanks_index += 1
            answers_index += 1
            guesses = 3
            print quiz
            if blanks_index == len(blanks):
                return you_win()

        else:
            guesses -= 1
            if guesses == 0:
                return you_lost()
                break
            print "Incorrect. Try again only " + str (guesses) + " guesses left!"

play_game()
```

Comment: This is not the right place for this question. Try posting on code-review.

Comment: Um... 18 lines? Why 18?

Comment: I am going thru a class and that is the feedback I am geeting

Comment: code works like I want just doesnt meet the specs per my reviewers

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `play_game()` subroutine reduced to 18 lines of code:

```
def play_game():
    data = game_data[get_level()]
    quiz, answers = data['quiz'], data['answers']
    index, guesses = 0, 3
    print quiz

    while index < len(blanks):
        user_answer = raw_input("So what's your answer to question " + blanks[index] + "? : ")

        if check_answer(user_answer, answers, index) == "right_answer":
            quiz = quiz.replace(blanks[index], user_answer.upper())
            print "\nLucky Guess!\n\n" + quiz
            guesses = 3
            index += 1
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            if guesses == 0:
                return you_lost()
            print "Incorrect. Try again only " + str(guesses) + " guesses left!"

    return you_win()
```

Tricky to do without being able to actually run the code.  Mostly just code cleanup.